# Novel involving a Gnome protagonist and very weird mating rituals

Tags: story-identification

I was reading a discussion on Gnomes and their mythological roots compared to Dungeons and Dragons and it sparked a memory of reading the first part of a fantasy book with a main protagonist who was a Gnome (I'm pretty sure, at least) and an early scene involved him saying goodbye to his wife and it sticks out in my head that the scene involved a lot of [armpit action because that was how Gnomes did it](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BizarreAlienReproduction). And there was something involving a bucket. That's all I remember, but now that's all that's running through my head, so I'm hoping someone can help me exorcise it by naming the book.

I would have read this somewhere in the 1990s in the United States. I don't think the other characters were Gnomes, which led to some culture shock.